# Como pular linha com View Bag?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte código

```
public ActionResult Action1 {
 TempData["msg"] = "Essa parte primeiro.\n Essa parte na linha de baixo.";
 return RedirectToAction("Action2");
}

public ActionResult Action2 {
  if (TempData["msg"] == null)
  {
     TempData["msg"] = "";
  }
  ViewBag.Message = TempData["msg"].ToString();
  return View();
}
```

Minha View está tem o seguinte:

```
<label style="color:red">@ViewBag.Message</label>
```

`/n` não tem funcionado para pular a linha, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não funcionam porque estamos devolvendo HTML para a apresentação, e não formatação de console.

Tem duas boas maneiras de resolver:

## 1. Usando CSS

```
<label style="color:red; white-space: pre-line">@ViewBag.Message</label>
```

## 2. Usando `String.Replace`

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(ViewBag.Message).Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

Comment: tu brilha muito cara! Muito obrigado mais uma vez!